# Python: Finding a mapping of all commits to their diffs for a given git repository

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am creating a tool for analysis of a Git repository, but have stumbled at something that should (seemingly) be quite simple.

I want to create a mapping of commits to diffs (i.e. actual blob changes line by line for the given commit); I have tried using GitPython but haven't had any success. I would like to achieve something like this:

```
def get_all_commits(REPO_URL):
    chromium_repo = Repo(REPO_URL)
    commits = list(chromium_repo.iter_commits())
    commmit_diffs = {}
    for commit in commits:
        diff = # get all blob changes for commit
        commit_diffs[commit.hexsha] = diff
    return commit_diffs
```

but am not sure how to get all blob changes for a given commit. `commit_diffs` would be in the form:

```
{ 232d8f39bedc0fb64d15eed4f46d6202c75066b6 : '<String detailing all blob changes for given commit>' }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some sample code with output and describe how the output should be different.  It looks there is a way to [get diff information](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#obtaining-diff-information), but perhaps it doesn't provide what you need?

Comment: @LexScarisbrick This is the first time I've used this library so I'm really not sure where to start; I've added a code sample to give some sort of idea

Comment: Be aware that this code will probably consume all your RAM as the chromium repo is quite big. That being said, have you tried `commit.diff()`?

Comment: @NilsWerner Yes I'm aware of memory issues; is a one time computation which will be stored in a db. Yes, although is a diff object not just a hash of the entire tree? How would I find differences between both trees efficiently? As you mentioned, the chromium repo is huge; having to compare the entire tree for every commit seems pretty ludicrous, unless there is something I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

I was unaware of the `git diff <commit_a> <commit_b>` command. The following (I think!) solves the issue:

```
def get_all_commits(REPO_URL):
    repo = Repo(REPO_URL)
    commits = list(repo.iter_commits())
    commmit_diffs = {}
    for index, commit in enumerate(commits):
        next_index = index + 1
        if next_index < len(commits):
            commit_diffs[commit.hexsha] = repo.git.diff(commits[next_index], commit)
    return commit_diffs
```